# Make PHP7 and PHP 8 live together

Tags: php, fpm, php-7.4, php-8

Make PHP7 and PHP 8 live together

I've upgraded from PHP 7 to PHP 8. As it's usually the case with PHP, I still have php7.4 in `/usr/bin` (alongside with php8.0). But, when I run the `php -v` command, it answers php8.0.

Since then, when trying to install software (for example Docker and VirtualBox), I get the error message `php7.4-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'`, followed by `Failed to start The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager`. It seems therefore that I need php7.4 to run to install such applications.

But I use PHP 8 functionalities to code a website and therefore don't want to get back to php7.4

Is there a way to use php8.0 and php7.4 at the same time? I could make PHP 8 work on a virtual machine but it's quite heavy.

I'm on Ubuntu 20 (but I'm not sure that this problem is OS-specific).

Zlotz

Comment: This is a great question.  I am in the same boat.  I run Moodle and Nextcloud.  Nextcloud 21 has some big improvements with php8.  BUT Moodle won't run on it. There has to be a good way to do this.

Answer (score 8):

As @Abilogos has mentioned in his answer, you can have multiple versions of php using `update-alternatives` and in cli, version which is set to default will work with `php` command but when it comes to run a specific version for a website with Apache/Nginx, it get's difficult and I also faced this thing recently when I wanted to make my code PHP 8 compatible parallely without hampering the existing working code and finally I was able to get it what I needed to make all this thing work.

Here is what I did on Fedora 33

**Step 1.** Installed PHP 8.0 as default version and using Remi repo, I've installed other PHP versions as well (5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3 & 7.4)

**Step 2.** I checked to `update-alternatives` to change the PHP version from 8.0 to 7.4 but there were not entry in it. So, I installed all these in `update-alternatives`

```
cp /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php80 
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php php /usr/bin/php80 0
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php php /opt/remi/php74/root/usr/bin/php 1
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php php /opt/remi/php73/root/usr/bin/php 2
```

**Step 3.** Now, it is very easy to change PHP version in cli at any time easily. Example, when your application have dependency on some libraries but they are PHP 8 compatible and you want to change the default PHP version to run the `composer install`

**Step 4.** Now, to configure website1 to run on PHP 8 and website2 to run on PHP 7.4, we need two PHP-FPM configured and running on different ports.

Change default PHP-FPM port

```
vim /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

;listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock
listen = 9001
```

Similarly, change PHP-FPM 7.4 port

```
vim /etc/opt/remi/php74/php-fpm.d/www.conf

;listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock
listen = 9002
```

Start/Restart PHP-FPM services

```
systemctl start php-fpm
systemctl start php74-php-fpm
```

**Step 5.** Change vhost configuration file to use different version of PHP for website1 and website2

```
vim /etc/httpd/conf.d/website1.conf 

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    # PHP 8.0
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001"
</FilesMatch>

vim /etc/httpd/conf.d/website2.conf

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    # PHP 7.4
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9002"
</FilesMatch>
```

Restart Apache/Nginx

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

And we're done

Comment: The original question was about Ubuntu, "remi" way is only for Fedora/RHEL/CentOS ;)

And, for CLI,  using the "module" command is probably simpler than setting "alternatives" (as already configured), try "module load php74"

Answer (score 1):

you can have multiple version of **php**, but only one can be set on as a default.

use this to set a default:

```
update-alternatives --config  php
```

using default:

```
php ./script.php
```

using specific version:

```
php7 ./script.php
php8 ./script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few great tutorials that solve this issue.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-multiple-php-versions-on-one-server-using-apache-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-18-04

https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-multiple-php-version-with-apache-on-ubuntu-20-04/

https://bobcares.com/blog/run-multiple-php-versions-apache-php-fpm/

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Please include all the necessary information in your answer, and quote from the linked page in case it becomes unavailable.

Answer (score -1):

Removing php7.4 with `sudo apt-get purge php7.4-common` solved my issue.

Comment: That sounds more like admitting defeat than solving the problem.

Comment: In fact, my goal was to install Docker and keep using PHP8. Do you think I should change the title of my topic ?

Comment: I doubt installing Docker was ever actually your problem, since there's no reason that would need the php-fpm service to be running. More likely, the install process just triggered some services to restart, and PHP 7.4 had got into a state where it couldn't start; the same error would probably have showed up if you rebooted the server.